# MediaElement in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am creating an app for a radio station and I am using MediaElement and MediaControls. But when I try to Stop or Pause the playback it does not work. After searching in MSDN I found that Start, Stop and Pause will not work in this case "Stop cannot be called while the timing engine drives media playback."

I manages to stop the playback by assigning null to mediaelement.Source but then the same problem appears in Start(). 
Can anyone explain what is going on here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it work without Pause Stop and Start. I just changed the mediaelement.PlaybackRate from 0 to 1 and that seems to work perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Do you use the Windows Store JavaScript or C# language?

If you make a Javascript Windows Store app, you can just use the html player. This got a play, mute and play status.

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: No I am using C#. I can't use JavaScript.

Comment: Have you follow the c# sample for the media player: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx

Comment: If I use a local .mp3 it works fine. But when I change it to streaming from the internet it loads fine when the app opens if I set the Source="link" in xaml but then Stop() or Pause() will not work. And although I can make it stop by setting Source=null then I have the same problem with the Start() method!

Comment: @Kwstas what audio types have you successfully got to play from streams? I am trying to play .m3u but no luck.